# Prepend directory to image source with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 5 rows on my website, each with an image in.

On click the image increases in size, but id then like to prepend a directory to the image source so it then becomes a different image.

Is this possible with jQuery?

**Currently**

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

**What I want**

```
<img src="hires/image.jpg" />
```

Ive read about using 'data-source' tags but I cant seem to get anything working?

**Tried**

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr({'src'}).prepend('hires');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, value) {
        return 'hires/' + value;
    });
});
```

It would prepend `hires/` on each click though. You can test whether it was already there using `.indexOf`:

```
$(this).attr('src', function(i, value) {
    return value.indexOf('hires/') === -1 ?  'hires/' + value : value;
});
```

If you want to toggle between `hires/` and not `hires/`, remove the string if it is present:

```
$(this).attr('src', function(i, value) {
    return value.indexOf('hires/') === -1 ?  
        'hires/' + value : 
        value.replace('hires/', '');
});
```

---

`.prepend` is a jQuery method to add DOM elements. It's not a native string method. Also the curly brackets are wrong there (syntax error).

Comment: Or you can just use one() to attach the event only one time. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, Say you had <li></li>, and that had a background image, is it possible to add it to the background image instead? –

Comment: @Liam: See my comment to Adil's answer ;)

Comment: @Liam it is possible but that's really different from what you asked initially, there are answers here that can be accepted. If you have a different question then you should create a new one.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @FelixKling, how about if I wanted to remove the 'hires', is that similar?

Comment: @Liam: Do you want to toggle between `hires` and not `hires` on click?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KXgU4/)**

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, value) {
        return 'hires/' + value;
    });   
});
```

Comment: This might not work... I'm not sure but I think `.src` will contain the full URL.

Comment: Thanks @Adil, Say you had <li></li>, and that had a background image, is it possible to add it to the background image instead?

Comment: @Liam: Editing the CSS is possible with different degrees of difficulty (depending on whether it is inline or a rule).

Comment: I wish I wasn't because I like properties more ;) You could always use `.getAttribute` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr({'src'}).prepend('hires');
```

There are a couple of things wrong in the above line.

`{'src'}` is a `SyntaxtError`. In JavaScript curly braces are used to create a new object (or a new block of code).
Objects are made up of key-value pairs, such as

```
var obj = { aKey: 42 };
obj.aKey // 42
```

**Update.**
Since ES2015 it's possible to omit the value, in case a variable with the same name of the key exists, and is accessible in the scope where the object is being created.

```
var aKey = 42;
var obj = { aKey }; // Note, there're no quotes
obj.aKey // 42
```

[$.fn.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) work both as getter, both as setter on the basis of the arguments it receives.
You may want to use it as `$(this).attr('src')` to get the current `src` attribute, and `$(this).attr('src', 'something')` to update it.

[$.fn.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) does not work on string. It's used to insert content, to the beginning of each matching element.

So finally that's the correct way to achieve your objective:

```
$(this).attr('src', 'hires/' + $(this).attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var imgSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', 'hires/' + imgSRC);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('src', "hires/" + $(this).attr('src'));
```